# Is it possible to create crosspoint(crossbar) switches with FPGA?

Tags: usb, switches, fpga, multiplexer, usb-c

we have 4 USB type C ports in one of our projects. We are using TPS65988 and TUSB546A-DCI for PD control and crossing USB signals. We want to take design to the next level with the crosspoint switch, making it a more flexible design. After some research, we couldn't find any crosspoint switches according to these parameters: at least 10gbps, 32+ inputs, 32+ outputs and budget-friendly. So, we are wondering is it possible to implement this kind of crosspoint in FPGA? Can we connect an IO to another IO like a multiplexer and at what speed?

Comment: Don't know anything about USB-C but this absolutely sounds possible. What speed, couldn't tell you, depends on the FPGA. If it can handle a USB-C signal at all, then it can surely make a crosspoint switch, which is about the *simplest* thing one could possibly do with such a signal.

Comment: also don't know the budget for an FPGA that handles 32 input and 32 output 10Gbps pairs. I believe on the Xilinx Artix-7 series (for example) most of the pins are capable of handling around 1Gbps and only a fairly small number of them have the special 10Gbps transceivers.

Comment: yeah okay I just checked the https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documents/selection-guides/7-series-product-selection-guide.pdf and only the very top-end one, a $6000 chip (!!!) specifies 32 transceivers capable of 10Gbps, so maybe forget what I just said.

Comment: though, did I misunderstand? You only have 4 ports, not 32

Comment: @user253751 we have 4 ports but 8 diff signals, we support alternate mode to connect a display. So I need to connect USB signals to dp port or USB PHY with a crosspoint switch.

Comment: so if I understand it right, it's like: 4x USB PHY + DP <==> crosspoint switch <==> 4x USB ports? Sounds like you're making a laptop without those pesky rules about which port can have which alternate mode. Neat puzzle

Comment: First I would suggest to work out what your actual switching requirements are. Presumably you don't actually need each port to be able to connect to each host controller - as long as each port can connect to *a* host controller then it's all good.

Comment: Exactly! :) I want the design to support DP on all ports.

Comment: I have one DP host and that's why I am using the tusb546 crosspoint for each port.

Comment: I wonder if this can be done fairly cheaply by using analog switches to get the signal from the DP host to 4 TUSB546s. However, you'd probably need an RF engineer to design it and prove it's reliable, and I am just a crazy ideas guy on the internet.

Comment: and now that I think about it even more... display port signals are 1-way... you might even be able to just split the signal 4 ways using RF techniques.

Comment: did you get it to work?